# How do I get the results of a fetch cycle in java based on an operating system? I am newbie to java I am looking for some advice

Tags: java, operating-system, memory-address, instruction-set, program-counter

How do i get the fetch cycle working  if i have to get the instruction address from memory and assign it to some area of ram? I am just starting to learn the language java any suggestions?
I want to get the address from the instruction and add the required ram to it I would like to know if i am on the right track.

How do i get the fetch cycle working  if i have to get the instruction address from memory and assign it to some area of ram? I am just starting to learn the language java any suggestions?
I want to get the address from the instruction and add the required ram to it I would like to know if i am on the right track.

```
 public int fetch(){
        program_counter =0;

        memory_address= 00000011100;

        instruction_register = 000110001;








        
        
        
        System.out.println("Processor is now fetching..");
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Java **is not C**, you do **not** work with memory, addresses, registers.

Comment: Your question is unclear anyway, and would still be so if posted in the C tag:(    Are you trying to design some kind of emulator?

Comment: yes its an emulator

Comment: to clear up the confusion I am basically asking how to write a fetch function in java

Comment: What instruction set are you emulating?  You'll need to simulate both the CPU and memory.  How to represent memory depends upon the instruction set.  For LC-3 for example, an array of unsigned short will work but for MIPS you might want an array of bytes, since that is a byte addressable machine.

Comment: its 16 bits for the instruction set